# Auto-Update via RSS (and keep history)

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, rss, importfeed

I have a Google Sheets that fetches some data via RSS. The RSS feed is updated once a day, everyday.

Is it possible for me to keep archive of all the new and historic data in the spreadsheet?

The data itself is not a lot, i.e. one new entry is added into the RSS feed per day. So far, I have it working fine but it only displays today's RSS feed, and not what was displayed yesterday or the day before. I would like to keep historical a record of all the data that has been displayed in the feed. So the spreadsheet would have to add one new entry per day, and perhaps shift the old one down (or append the new entry to the bottom of the sheet).

I cannot publish my spreadsheet here but as an example, I have set up a public [spreadsheet with a Twitter RSS feed](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AoFQ0D-Bv55QdFFKb3prR1NKOWd4eUpQemh4MEJZbUE&hl=en_GB&authkey=CNSfxo0E).

My spreadsheet is very similar to the one above and I would like to retain a copy of every new item that is added once a day.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just saw this question: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=2401ad0171e73978&hl=en. Its exactly what I am looking for - last answer seems a little vague though.

Comment: did you find the solution? I am in need of same functionality, but haven't been able to figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

`=ImportFeed(URL; [feedQuery | itemQuery]; [headers]; [numItems])`.

This function imports an RSS or ATOM feed, just as you can in Google Reader.

For more information on this go to : [Functions for external Data : Functions - Google Docs help](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&query=importfeed&answer=75507)

Answer (score 0):

Write a script that archives your data and set it as time-driven.